# Setup Apache Camel Rest route using Java DSL on Wildfly Swarm

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel, wildfly-swarm

I'm trying to setup a Camel Rest service in Wildfly Swarm and I'm not sure how the `RouteBuilder` class gets instantiated, or even how the `CamelContext` is instantiated. I've downloaded the Wildfly Swarm examples and had a look at the Camel CXF-JAXRS project, which makes sense, but it uses XML to define the route. I'd like to use Java DSL. My `RouteBuilder` class looks like this:

```
public class GreetingService extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        System.out.println("RouteBuilder.configure");
        restConfiguration().host("localhost").port("9797");
        rest("/say")
                .get("/hello").to("direct:hello")
                .get("/bye").consumes("application/json").to("direct:bye")
                .post("/bye").to("mock:update");

            from("direct:hello")
                .transform().constant("Hello World");
            from("direct:bye")
                .transform().constant("Bye World");
    } 
}
```

I have tried this with and without the `camel-context.xml` file. Swarm start up, but I can't browse to the rest service endpoint.

How does the `RouteBuilder` get called? Should I have some sort of `main` method that instantiates the `CamelContext`?

I am using Widlfy Swarm 2017.8.1 and the class is in a `war` file.

Comment: Did you apply the wildfly camel patches. I did this a while ago and there was some steps I had to do before getting it to work. Hoe gaan dit met Slaapstad?

Comment: @Namphibian baie lekker :) I am using mvn to manage the Wildfly Swarm version (and all it's dependencies) and it's on 2017.8.1 which is the latest stable version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this listener in your web.xml to bootstrap camel.
 `org.apache.camel.component.servletlistener.SimpleCamelServletContextListener`
Or you can use spring to define camel context

Comment: That works. I added a `src/main/resources/camel/camel-context.xml` file and specified the package where the `RouteBuilder` class is like this: `<camelContext id="simpleTransform"> <packageScan><package>za.co.camel.rest</package></packageScan></camelContext>`